# React async data fetch does not fetch data on static build

Tags: reactjs, build, gatsby, netlify, sanity

- I'm building a static site using [Sanity.io](https://www.sanity.io/) and [Gatsby.js](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/).
- The data is hosted through Sanity and I'm fetching it via [GROQ](https://www.sanity.io/docs/groq).
- Host and build is on [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/).

The problem is that when I build I only get a rendered result of `Loading`. It does work in development. (which, I'm sure is because of hotloading)

**How would I build a render a (async) data fetch for a build?** I don't want to have this in a `componentDidMount()` or `useEffect()` Because from what I understand then the query would be client side. that would result in an API request for every page load, right? I just want one on build instead.

**Can I pause the build/render just as long as it has no data yet?**

Below is my simplified code

```
    import React from "react"
    import useSWR from "swr"
    import client from "../../../../../sanityClient"
    import BlockCarousel from "../blockCarousel/blockCarousel"
    
    const BlockCarouselBlog = ({ block }) => {
      const skip = 0
      const limit = block.itemAmount ? block.itemAmount : 10
      const params = { skip, limit: skip + limit - 1 }
      let {
        data,
        error,
      } = useSWR(
        '*[_type == "blog"] | order(_createdAt asc) [$skip..$limit]',
        query => client.fetch(query, params)
      )
    
      if (error) console.log(error)
      if (!data) return <div>Loading</div>
    
      block.blocks = data
    
      return <BlockCarousel block={block} />
    
    }
    export default BlockCarouselBlog
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use GROQ to fetch data this way, and you don't want to do it client side, you probably want to either create a custom source plugin that creates GraphQL nodes using Gatsby's APIs, or define a pre-build function that will fetch all of your data and make it available in static JSON files or similar, then import those into your components or fetch them client side.

Using GROQ with Gatsby without using GraphQL for statically rendered components is going to be a bunch of additional work, and you lose a lot of the value of Gatsby over something like Next.js.